# Unicode string from Windows .NET to Android Java

Tags: java, android, .net, encoding

Please, give me the correct transformation set of functions to in Java to receive correct result.

## Windows.NET part.

Some UNICODE string data is converted to byte array using

`Encoding.Unicode.ToBytes(SomeString);`

## Android Java

`byte[]` buffer is transferred to Android Java as it is.
Using `new String(byte[], "utf-16")` doesn't give the correct string.
Someone said it is because of Big or Little ending order of one char byte.
I'am not sure if Unicode.Net and utf-16 are the same. Is it the same?

Is there a standard library that is responsible for such transformation or every programmer should develop own function to convert from big to little endians and so on?

the study has shown that extra -1 -2 are added under Java.. What these two bytes means?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra first two bytes [-1, -2] are `Byte Order Mark (BOM)`. You can read more about it on [Wiki Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

You should add `BOM` at the beginning of your byte[]. I used the following code snippet in C# to convert String to byte[] including BOM.

```
var result = Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble().Concat(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Sample Unicode Text")).ToArray();
```